# Exporting attributes from QGIS to .dxf/dwg

Tags: qgis, dxf, cad, dwg

I have a QGIS point layer with attributes in table. I want to export a layer with some of the attributes as a CAD block with attributes. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: If you have Civil3D then it can import shapefiles and it retains attributes, there are tutorials on labelling in Civil3D using those attributes.

Comment: If you look at the ESRI help it seem that creating a DWG with block definition and adding specific field to your points does the trick in ArcMap, you may try something similar in QGIS and tell us if it work (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/exporting-attributes-to-autocad-block-attributes.htm)

Comment: Did you try the QGIS "export to dxf" functionality? What's missing in the result?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn 
I tried this functionalty, but in result I have only marked points. They haven't any atrributes and in .dxf this points are exported as polylines, no blocks.

Comment: The only free tool I've found so far to export shp features as blocks with attributes is dxfAuthor, an ancient and very clunky tool from 1997 http://priede.bf.lu.lv/ftp/pub/TIS/failu_paarveide/shp2dxf/about.htm I would be very interested in a modern FOSS option.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use 'MAPIMPORT' in autocad to import shapefiles and some other formats. The map import window will give you some choices on how to import it (as a block, as a text, give the shapefile attributes to the block, import data table...)

The block's attributes will have to match the shapefiles's attributes to be imported correctly