# Exporting to DXF with properties QGIS 3.12

Tags: export, dxf, autocad

I am using QGIS 3.12. Is there a way I can export my project to DXF including the information in the properties table, so I will be able to see the properties of the feature in AutoCAD?

Comment: I know how to export the project but it doesn't add the informationn from the properties table. Thank you anyway

Comment: From https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336182/exporting-attributes-from-qgis-to-dxf-dwg it does not seems possible from QGIS except if new changes since but there are clues in the discussion to use other tools to achieve your goal (a freeware or an Autocad function)